# Visual Studio 2015 not compiling TypeScript as part of a ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, typescript, npm, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS2015 and am trying to produce an Angular app using TypeScript inside of a ASP.NET Core project, but no matter what I try, I cannot get my Angular virtual project to be transpiled into the `wwwroot` folder, despite VS2015 recognizing it as a TypeScript Virtual Project. Here is my project structure:

[image]

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../../wwwroot/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

VS does not compile this automatically, and even running `npm run tsc:w main.ts` from the command line results in a file not found error. How can I get my ts files to build?

Comment: I went through similar topic few weeks ago with Angular2 and ts. Although I'm a bit Visual Studio purist to integrate all in one place along with c# backend, lots of reading surprisingly convinced me to try VS Code for front end and Angular . For me it turned out much more seamless integration with angular, and some really nice suprises with comfort of working on front end (esp.breakthrough speed compared to vs)

Comment: @Turo don't have that option sadly

Comment: I had the same problem with vs2015 update 3. For me the solution was to manually setting the TypeScript version to be 1.7 or higher:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021808/vs2015-adding-watch-true-to-tsconfig-json-causing-jserrorscriptexception-0x/39022452#39022452

Answer (score 0):

@EchoLogic, try to rename your *Angular* folder to *scripts*, it should work.

Comment: @SambhavSharma This is not requesting information from the author.  It's proposing a solution.  It *is* an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your outdir is relative to the tsconfig.json so your path should be something like: ../wwwroot/.  Here is an example of my own tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"removeComments": false,
"noImplicitAny": false,
"outFile": "../wwwroot/app/app.js"
  },
"compileOnSave": true,
"files": [
  "../typings/main.d.ts",
  "app.module.ts",
  "app.config.ts",
  "home.controller.ts",
  "myTeam.controller.ts"
  ]}
```

I also prefer to build typescript through gulp.  I've posted two articles on how to do this:

Here you can find a complete step by step guide on how to configure your ASP.NET Core app to compile typescript:
[ASP.NET Core: modify an Angular app to use typescript](http://www.vandiest.biz/?p=3401)

And how to do the same with a Gulp workflow: 
[ASP.NET Core: Building Typescript with Gulp](http://www.vandiest.biz/?p=3601)