# VS2015: Adding "watch": true to tsconfig.json causing JsErrorScriptException (0x30001)

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core-rc1

I have created a dummy basic project in **VS2015 Community Update 3**, Version 14.0.25424.00.
(Using this great tutorial:  [aspnet-core-web-api-angularjs-2](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/cascading-dropdown-list-aspnet-core-web-api-angularjs-2/) ).

This angular-2 project has some .ts files.

The problem:

Instead of being transpiled ("compiled") to .js files **every time a file is being saved**, the .ts files being transpiled **once and only at BUILD** time of the SERVER-SIDE  project.
(clicking F5 from visual studio).

I google it and found out that I should add "watch": true
to the tsconfig.json file:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "watch": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/lib"
  ]
}
```

However, now I am getting an error at BUILD time:
Error       'JsErrorScriptException (0x30001)'. ASPNETCoreAngular2Demo  C:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ASPNETCoreAngular2Demo\src\ASPNETCoreAngular2Demo\Unknown output 1

According to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7362) post, the solution in VS2015 update 2 is to add to the tsconfig file:

```
"compileOnSave": true
```

However, this didn't work for me in my update 3 version.

From the cmd I run the following:

> `>tsc -v
>    Version 1.0.3.0`

Which I think is pretty old but I don't know how to update it, because running:

```
>npm install -g typescript@* --save
```

didn't change the current version.

What do you suggest?
I am desperate..

TNX,

Answer (score 2):

WoW, poor Microsoft..

The issue here is that on installing VS2015, I got TypeScript 1.8,
But it didn't update the PATH env variable of Windows 10,
So I was actually using the 1.0 version.

I had to update it manually with the help of [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35258446/4572425) .

(be aware of the comment there to use "compileOnSave": true on win10 os).

Now it's WORK (-;